# Autoremove and Install loop on packages

Tags: apt

I am seeing ubuntu requiring to install and then uninstall 4 packages as a loop. Here is some output from the console:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libcec4 libp8-platform2 libva-drm1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libcec4 libp8-platform2 libva-drm1
The following packages have been kept back:
  kodi kodi-bin
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
Need to get 229 kB of archives.
After this operation, 777 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Ignore Kodi packages, I m not in a hurry to go from 16.1 to 17.0.

Notes: I m not listing `sudo apt update` It's what you would expect. If I click to install said packages, then auto remove will ask me to delete them. I think this issue propped up after I uninstalled nexcloud-client package from the previous ppa and re-installed it from nextcloud-dev ppa but I'm not sure.

Any thoughts on what I should do to fix this?

edit - update:

Regarding the 1st comment, on the same terminal that gave the above results:

```
sudo apt-mark manual libcec4
libcec4 can not be marked as it is not installed.
```

Also:

```
$ apt-cache policy libcec4
libcec4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.1.1~xenial
  Version table:
     4.0.1.1~xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Hm, This appears to be related to kodi, maybe those packages are required for 17.0?

Comment: Apt-mark one package as 'manual'

Comment: Run the command for one package and got the result I added in question. Is there a way to check if they are required as dependencies for a package?

Comment: If they were not dependencies, apt would not try to install them. Use `apt-cache policy <packagename>` to determine the offending PPA. Disable the PPA, and uninstall all packages from that PPA.

Comment: Updated question. This looks like it is related to kodi. Since I don't want to uninstall it is there any other option?

Comment: Find and install packages from reputable sources that are compatible with your current release of Ubuntu. Don't mix releases. Minimize your PPAs. FrankenUbuntus break easily.

Comment: This is the official kodi stable ppa, I can't vouch for how reputable it is but my guess is that they are legit. That doesn't mean they can't make mistakes. I m just trying to find out what happened.

Comment: You question is 'how to fix?', not 'what happened?'. What happened is clear enough already - you built a FrankenUbuntu (too many PPAs), and it broke. It doesn't much matter whether it was Kodi PPA or some other PPA that caused the breakage this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @user535733 's suggestion I set the offending packages to manual by typing

```
sudo apt-mark manual libcec4 libp8-platform2 libva-drm1
```

P.S. I could dist-upgrade to kodi17 to see what would happen then but I don't have the time to learn the new interface and reconfigure it for my use-case yet.